# Change in Limits of Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

I'm working on the below problem of finding area:
$$
x=\frac{y^4}{4}+\frac{1}{8y^2}
$$
is revolved around $x$-axis in $1\leq y\leq 2$.

**My Solution**
The area swept by a curve $f(x)$ by revolving it around $x$-axis between $a\leq x\leq b$ is given by
$$
A=2\pi\int_a^b y\sqrt{1+\big[y'\big]^2}dx
$$
Now
$$
y'=\frac{4y^3}{4y^6-1}
$$
and
$$
\sqrt{1+\big[y'\big]^2}=\frac{4y^6+1}{4y^6-1}
$$
Clearly,
$$
\sqrt{1+\big[y'\big]^2}=\frac{4y^6+1}{4y^3}y'
$$

Plugging these results into the area formula, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
A &= 2\pi\int_a^b y\left(\frac{4y^6+1}{4y^3}\right)y'dx \\
&= 2\pi\int_a^b \left(\frac{4y^6+1}{4y^2}\right)dy \\
\end{aligned}
$$

**Notice that**, when I first stated the equation for area, the limits of integration, $a$ and $b$, are numbers on the $x$-axis (integration was with respect to $x$). But as we can see, the integral has changed into one where we are now evaluating with respect to $y$ and I ended up intuitively changing the limits to numbers on the $y$-axis and then evaluating. That is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
A &= 2\pi\int_1^2 \left(\frac{4y^6+1}{4y^2}\right)dy \\
&= \frac{253\pi}{20}
\end{aligned}
$$
which ended up as the correct answer.

**Then I got this doubt**:
While manipulating the integral that was with respect to $x$ into the integral with respect to $y$, I don't understand how the limits of integration changed from numbers on the $x$-axis to those on the $y$-axis.

Someone please help me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your confusion arises with the symbols used for $y(x)$ as a function and $y$ as a variable in the last step.

Let proceed by steps from here

$$A = 2\pi\int_a^b \left(\frac{4[y(x)]^6+1}{4[y(x)]^2}\right)y'(x)dx $$

we are changing variable $y(x)=u \implies y'(x) dx = du$ to obtain (we have used $u$ instead of $y$)

$$A = 2\pi\int_{y(a)}^{y(b)} \left(\frac{4u^6+1}{4u^2}\right)du $$

with $y(a)=1$ and $y(b)=2$.

Comment: Thank you! That was a good explanation.

Comment: @AbhishekAUdupa You are welcome! Bye